# Restarting threads from saved contexts

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to implement a checkpointing scheme for multithreaded applications by using fork. I will take the checkpoint at a safe location such as a barrier. One thread will call fork to replicate the address space and signals will be sent to all other threads so that they can save their contexts and write it to a file.

The forked process will not run initially. Only when restart from checkpoint is required, a signal would be sent to it so it can start running. At that point, the threads who were not forked but whose contexts were saved, will be recreated from the saved contexts.

My first question is if it is enough to recreate threads from saved contexts and run them from there, if i assume there was no lock held, no signal pending during checkpoint etc... . Lastly, how a thread can be created to run from a known context.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Distributed MultiThreaded Checkpointing (http://dmtcp.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is **not possible** without major integration with the pthreads implementation. Internal thread structures will likely contain their own kernel-space thread ids, which will be different in the restored contexts.

It sounds to me like what you really want is `forkall`, which is non-trivial to implement. I don't think barriers are useful at all for what you're trying to accomplish. Asynchronous interruption and checkpointing is just as good as synchronized.

If you want to try hacking `forkall` into glibc, you should start out by looking at the `setxid` code NPTL uses for synchronizing `setuid()` calls between threads using signals. The same principle is what's needed to implement `forkall`, but you'd basically call `setjmp` instead of `setuid` in the signal handlers, and then `longjmp` back into them after making new threads in the child. After that you'd have to patch up the thread structures to have the right pid/tid values, free the excess new stacks that were created, etc.

**Edit:** Since the `setxid` code in glibc/NPTL is rather dense reading for someone not familiar with the codebase, you might instead look at the corresponding code I have in musl, called `__synccall`:

http://git.etalabs.net/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=musl;a=blob;f=src/thread/synccall.c;h=91ac5eb77322da7393f778da29d35fb3c2def15d;hb=HEAD

It uses a signal to synchronize all threads, then runs a callback sequentially in each thread one-by-one. To implement `forkall`, you'd want to do something like this prior to the fork, but instead of a callback, simply save jump buffers for each thread except the calling thread (you can't use a callback for this because the return would invalidate the jump buffer you just saved), then perform the `fork` from the calling thread. After that, you would make `N` new threads, and have them jump back to the old threads' saved jump buffers, and destroy their new (unneeded) stacks. You'd also need to make the right syscall to update their thread register (e.g. `%gs` on x86) and tid address.

Then you need to take these ideas and integrate them with glibc's thread allocation and thread stack cache framework. :-)

Comment: Ya I am looking the solaris fork and forkall implementation and comparing its fork with linux fork, to see if I can add something to it for forkall. But their implementation differs a lot and I suppose it would be pretty complicated to write the forkall for linux.

Comment: I doubt Solaris implementation will be useful to look at. Most of how you implement `forkall` is dependent on how the userspace side of your threads implementation works, which is probably completely different from Solaris's.

Comment: Unfortunately I think the situation is a bit worse... or rather a lot worse. Normally lock owners are identified by their kernelspace thread id (and there are multiple reasons for this, some not-so-good but others very good), and those will all change after the fork. So in order for a `forkall` to work correctly, you'd need to be able to find and fix the owner fields in all locks. This means your scheme of using a "safe location"/barrier as the checkpoint might be a viable fix though, if you can ensure that no locks are held at the barrier location.